# Aligning a Custom Checkbox In the Center With Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

A friend gave me some code for a To-Do list with custom checkboxes, and I've been struggling to center-align the Custom Checkbox with the to-do list text using Flexbox (using the bootstrap classes), as you can see here:

Here is a Code Pen with the code:
https://codepen.io/tanner-brandt/pen/vYGvRee

[image]

I've been trying to align the checkbox item child in the center when the text takes up multiple rows, but the checkbox is staying at the top. Meanwhile my delete button (the X button off to the right of the text) seems to be responding correctly. Can anyone help me spot the issue?

Comment: Add `top: 50%;transform:translateY(-50%);` to both `.input-helper:before` and `.input-helper:after`

Comment: Thanks Zohir, works great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that because your input checkbox has `position: absolute;`. The easiest way in your case would be to position the checkbox with css like this:

```
.form-check .form-check-label input[type="checkbox"]+.input-helper:before, 
.form-check .form-check-label input[type="checkbox"]+.input-helper:after {
  top: calc(50% - 9px);
}
```

Note that you have input that is `height: 18px;` so when you add `top: 50%;` you also need to reduce the top value by half of element height...

Comment: Thanks Leon, appreciate it